# Angular Form Custom Validators

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I'm currently using Angular 8 and I have an issue with custom validator. The only validator that works is Validators.minLength(3). **noEmptyStringValidator** **doesn't work**, even though I can print 'here' into validator function. Could you help me?

The context is the following:

**no-empty-string.validator.ts**

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function noEmptyStringValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    console.log('here');

    return control.value && control.value.trim().length > 0 ? { noEmptyString: { valid: true } } : null;
}
```

**myComponent.component.ts**

```
...
topicLabelControl = new FormControl();
...
this.topicLabelControl.setValidators([ Validators.minLength(3), noEmptyStringValidator ]);
...
console.log(this.topicLabelControl.valid);
```

**myComponent.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"
      (keydown.enter)="handleEnterKey()">
      <input type="text"
        matInput
        [formControl]="topicLabelControl"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto" />
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">...
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems to be inverted: if the input is valid the validator should return `null`, if invalid an object whose key identifies the error. (The value can be anything, and can be used to report any additional information):

```js
return control.value && control.value.trim().length > 0 ? null : { noEmptyString: true };
```